# deleting a node anywhere in a linked list

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I know how to remove a node from the front of a singly linked list, but I have no idea how to remove one from any arbitrary location.

In my specific problem, I continue to pass an integer value x into each node in the linked list. I can add and delete, but there is a function I need to write where if I've identified two x's that are the same, I delete the other instance.

I can give examples of my code if anyone needs examples of what I've done so far. Thanks for any and all responses

Also, I'm working with a singly linked list.

Answer (score 1):

this is a disadvantage that singly linked list has. It requires iteration to perform deletion since you can not find the previous element of an arbitrary element. What you can find is its next element. You have to iterate from the head of the lists to find its previous element.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What I was doing, when I was looking into lists, and what not is: when iterating through list, I kept the pointer to the previous element in a separate variable, and if I decided that I needed to delete current element, I already had the pointer to the previous element at hand.

So, pseudo-code wise (to better illustrate it), it would be something like this:

```
prevValue = NULL
for curValue = root; curValue != NULL; curValue = curValue->Next
LOOP
IF *need to delete curValue*
THEN
    IF prevValue == NULL
    THEN
        root = curValue->Next
        delete curValue
        curValue = root
    ELSE
        prevValue->Next = curValue->Next
        delete curValue
        curValue = prevValue
    END IF
END IF
prevValue = curValue
END LOOP
```

Comment: I tried what you said using a while loop. Problem is, I don't know quite what to do delete my node.

Comment: Node* removeAge=head;
     while(removeAge!=NULL)
     {
      if(test_age_contained_in_singly_linked_list(x))
      {
       //Any ideas here? 
      }


      removeAge=removeAge->next;
     }

Comment: Thank you by the way, you and everyone here made very clear sense on what to do! How do I go about deleting the node inside my if statement?

Comment: Well, the key is, to remember the previous element of the list, when iterating through it (*points at the pseudo-code I have written*). And, when you have the previous element, you can do prevValue->Next = curValue->Next; delete curValue. The only difference is when you need to delete the first element of the list (i.e. when prevValue == NULL), then you just do root = curValue->Next; delete curValue.

Answer (score 1):

Because each node only has a link to the subsequent node, you would have to iterate over the entire list to obtain the previous element, then link the previous with the next node. (next, as in the one after that you wish to remove)

Answer (score 0):

node*remove(node*head,int d){

```
if(head==NULL)
    cout<<"empty linked list\n";
else {
    node*curr=head,*pre=NULL;
    while (curr!=NULL && curr->data !=d)
    {
        pre=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    if(curr==NULL)
        cout<<"Mahloch this number not found\n";
    else {
        if(pre==NULL)
            head=curr->next;
        else
            pre->next=curr->next;
        curr->next=NULL;
      delete(curr); } 

}return head;
```

}

Comment: Provide a description with your answers, it will help others understand your method.